# Is there a medical database with data (measured from patients) for research?

Tags: medications, database, healthcare-data

I am currently working on a mathematical project about optimisation problems in pharmacokinetics. To make it more practical and interesting, I was thinking of making some computations on actual data. I am looking for concentrations in plasma of various drugs (e.g. aspirin, alcohol, caffeine,...) measured at several points after the administration, e.g. every 10 minutes. Does anyone know of any such database with medical data? I am looking for something genuine and free.

Comment: Did you found anything?

Comment: I am guessing no such database is available, but on the off-chance you found one, could you share it?